# Is it possible to reference a nested class from a subclass like in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

There is a Java library I'm interacting with that has the following:

```java
class Superclass {
    static class Nested {}
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {}
```

This is code is illegal in Kotlin:

```
class Test() {
    val thing1 = Superclass.Nested()
    val thing2 = Subclass.Nested()
}
```

The compiler says that `Subclass.Nested` is an unresolved reference. However, the equivalent Java code is not illegal:

```java
class Test {
    Superclass.Nested thing1 = new Superclass.Nested();
    Subclass.Nested thing2 = new Subclass.Nested();
}
```

Is there some other way in Kotlin to reference a nested class by qualifying it with a subclass instead of the superclass?

(Why? Because there is an unusual deprecation pattern in play here: `Superclass` is deprecated and is being replaced by `Subclass`. The `Nested` class is going to be moved into `Subclass` later. That is the external constraint I am working under.)

Comment: I am glad that not everything that works in Java is also possible in Kotlin. What is the benefit of using `Subclass.Nested()` when it is a static nested class of `Superclass`? Why not just use `Superclass.Nested()` then? I am also glad that accessing a `static` field from a Kotlin instance isn't working too ;-) maybe that's even related...

Comment: @Roland I explained my constraints in the final paragraph. Was the explanation unclear?

Comment: No, it wasn't...I was disturbed writing this comment (which should have followed just a minute after ;-)) Regarding your refactoring issue: I would keep the `Superclass.Nested()` until the new `Nested` inside of `Subclass` exists... as long as this isn't the case, `Superclass` and `Superclass.Nested` are still needed... while there are ways to have something like `Subclass.Nested()` in place, these are just workarounds... either you need that nested class again or you don't... simulating it is there, because it worked that way in Java, doesn't seem to be the best excuse for me...

Comment: Agreed that continuing to reference `Superclass.Nested` is a viable option for the time being. I was just trying to get ahead of the curve so that when `Superclass` does eventually get removed in favor of `Subclass` we will already be ready for it.

Comment: as `Nested` is a substantial part of `Superclass` (it is translated to a static inner class), it makes no real sense to simulate it being there for `Subclass`. If `Superclass` then gets removed, your `Subclass` is still not ready as long as it doesn't contain that `Nested` inner class. Moreover your `Subclass` is a subclass of `Superclass`, so basically you still have work to do, when `Superclass` finally gets removed... so I don't see any refactoring problem here besides `Subclass` being a subclass of `Superclass` ;-)

Comment: ok... I just saw your adapted question... as both, `Superclass` and `Subclass` aren't under your control, that seems to be a pity, that `Subclass.Nested()` then doesn't work... I would probably work with a `typealias` meanwhile... that however still references `Superclass`, but you can limit the usage on a single line: `typealias BetterNameForNested = Superclass.Nested`

Comment: Note, that even though I am glad that this isn't working, this doesn't mean, that this was also intended.... it could still be a bug... actually I didn't find anything related to it yet (whether it should be allowed or not)... so maybe you have better luck finding something in the docs or issues than me... maybe you also find something or want to ask in the [Kotlin forums](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this solves your problem, buy you can access the Nested class from the Subclass, so you could do something like this:

```
open class Superclass {
    class Nested
}

class Subclass : Superclass() {

    companion object Nested {
        operator fun invoke(): Superclass.Nested = Nested()
    }

}

class Test() {
    val thing1 = Superclass.Nested()
    val thing2 = Subclass.Nested()
}
```

Also, to avoid any confunsion you could just make a function that creates the Nested class

```
class Subclass : Superclass() {

    companion object {
        fun createNested() = Nested()
    }

}
```

Comment: No reason to make `Nested` a _companion_ object in the first case. And you can add type alias `type Nested = Superclass.Nested` to make it usable as a type, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it won't work in my case; `Superclass` and `Subclass` are part of a library written in Java which won't change. (I'm sorry I didn't make this clear in the original question -- I'll update it.) I *can* PR the library to make a compatibility change and it might be accepted, but I can't think of any change that will make `Nested` accessible from Kotlin via `Subclass`. `Nested` will not be moved _yet_ (but it will eventually). The best I've come up with is subclassing `Nested` inside of `Subclass`, but that's pretty gross.

Comment: @ean5533 actually having `Nested` inside of `Subclass` seems the only clean way for me to do what you want... and if you want to refactor that in future that seems also the right way... but why do you need to do it immediately? is it a refactoring or do you want to keep imports similar or what is your real purpose?

Comment: I'm just trying to stop using the deprecated classes as quickly as possible rather than waiting for the breaking change to land. Since that isn't possible in this case we'll just have to wait for the change to occur.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't access the source code or have to wait for the PR to be approved, I probably would try it with [`typealias`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) instead, e.g.:

```
typealias MyNested = Superclass.Nested
```

and use it like:

```
MyNested()
```

As soon as `Superclass` is obsolete you only need to replace the type-alias, e.g.:

```
typealias MyNested = Subclass.Nested
```

That way you only have 1 place where you need to adapt your code when `Superclass` is removed.

It's now really a pity that both classes aren't under your control and that this feature of Java doesn't work in Kotlin. On the other hand I am really glad that it isn't. Something like `Subclass.Nested` when there actually isn't any such nested class there, isn't really convenient in my opinion. However, that's also what is possible with extension functions... so now I am in conflict ;-)

As also said in the comment: there might be a chance that this could also just be a bug. I didn't find any sources yet whether this was a deliberate design decision or not. It sounds good to me, but that doesn't mean it was intentional. You may want to ask the same question in the [Kotlin forums](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/) or [open an issue](https://kotl.in/issue) and link it here.

Comment: Looks like it is intentionally disallowed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17717

Comment: I spoke too soon, that issue says that it should work for classes defined in Java, but there was never any followup...

Comment: @ean5533 good catch! I wonder how one could differentiate between Kotlin nested classes and Java ones when at the end both are the same in the resulting byte code... So it seems to me that either both should work or none...